# Android Studio : If i click the enter in software keyboard it will go to a fragment or activity

Tags: android

I want to open an activity or fragment using the software keyboard instead of button please help me how.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this once add your widget id with setOnKeyListener.

```
 yourEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
               public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                         if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) ||
                                (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                                   //do your action here
                                 
                                   return true;
                                  }
                          return false;
                          }
           });
```

Comment: @PauloTrevorRegacho if its useful for you please upvote and it will make community help with profile.